# How can we create asynchronous API in django?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, django-celery

I want to create a third party chatbot API which is asynchronous and replies "ok" after 10 seconds pause.

```
import time

def wait():
    time.sleep(10)
    return "ok"

# views.py
def api(request):
    return wait()
```

I have tried celery for the same as follows where I am waiting for celery response in view itself:

```
import time
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def wait():
    time.sleep(10)
    return "ok"

# views.py
def api(request):
    a = wait.delay()
    work = AsyncResult(a.id)
    while True:
        if work.ready():
           return work.get(timeout=1)
```

But this solution works synchronously and makes no difference. How can we make it asynchronous without asking our user to keep on requesting until the result is received?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is to define a periodic task. Please have a look at [`django-celery-beat`](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @gutsytechster Can you explain how it works.

Comment: Actually what you want to do in 10 secs (sleep(10)) ?

Comment: django celery beat is also not the answer. celery is intended for defered or periodic tasks. It is will not transform a blocking django view  in an asynchronous non blocking one. and if you just stay blocking one the related django worker thread or process is not available for treating other requests.
Django is not blocking except the new django 3.x one. which can be non blocking.  for some views. (e.g. the'yre not allowed to access the ORM)
There you could create an asynchronous view,.

Comment: You might want to have a look at channels. https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @embe. I mentioned channels in my answer, but channels doesn't implement blocking asynchronous  requests as far as I know. So the API logic had to be changed. But I'm not a channels expert, so perhaps there is a feature I don't know

Comment: After some more thinking:
There are many potential solutions. But if you want to get a good answer you had to explain some more details.

If the details are wrong many of the  solutions might consume too many resources (processes / threads / or just RAM)

Do you really just want to reply OK after 10 seconds or do you you want to reply OK after something else happened (a message arrived)

Is the idea, that you have many requests to this blocking API from many clients and that you have one task, that analyses received messages and will decide when to deblock which request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in @Blusky's answer:
The asynchronous API will exist in django 3.X. **not before**.

If this is not an option, then the answer is just **no**.

Please note as well, that even with django 3.X any django code, that accesses the database will **not** be asynchronous it had to be executed in a thread (thread pool)

Celery is intended for background tasks or deferred tasks, but celery will never return an  HTTP response as it didn't receive the HTTP request to which it should respond to. Celery is also not asyncio friendly.

You might have to think of changing your architecture / implementation.
Look at your overall problem and ask yourself whether you really need an asynchronous API with Django.

Is this API intended for browser applications or for machine to machine applications?

Could your client's use web sockets and wait for the answer?

**Could you separate blocking and non blocking parts** on your server side?
Use django for everything non blocking, for everything periodic / deferred (django + celelry) and implement the asynchronous part with web server plugins or python ASGI code or web sockets.

Some ideas

**Use Django + nginx nchan (if your web server is nginx)**

Link to nchan: https://nchan.io/
your API call would create a task id, start a celery task, return immediately the task id or a polling url.

The polling URL would be handled for example via an nchan  long polling channel.
your client connects to the url corresponding to an nchan long polling channel and celery deblocks it whenever you're  task is finished (the 10s are over)

**Use Django + an ASGI server + one handcoded view and use strategy similiar to nginx nchan**

Same logic as above, but you don't use nginx nchan, but implement it yourself

**Use an ASGI server + a non blocking framework (or just some hand coded ASGI views) for all blocking urls and Django for the rest.**

They might exchange data via the data base, local files or via local http requests.

**Just stay blocking and throw enough worker processes / threads at your server**

This is probably the worst suggestion, but if it is just for personal use,
and you know how many requests you will have in parallel then just make sure you have enough Django workers, so that you can afford to be blocking.
I this case you would block an entire Django worker for each slow request.

**Use websockets. e.g. with the channels module for Django**

Websockets can be implemented with earlier versions of django (>= 2.2) with the django channels module (`pip install channels`) ( https://github.com/django/channels )

You need an ASGI server to server the asynchronous part. You could use for example Daphne ot uvicorn (The channel doc explains this rather well)

**Addendum 2020-06-01: simple async example calling synchronous django code**

Following code uses the starlette module as it seems quite simple and small

**miniasyncio.py**

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import os
import django
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.responses import Response
from starlette.routing import Route

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'pjt.settings')
django.setup()

from django_app.xxx import synchronous_func1
from django_app.xxx import synchronous_func2

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

async def simple_slow(request):
    """ simple function, that sleeps in an async matter """
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return Response('hello world')

async def call_slow_dj_funcs(request):
    """ slow django code will be called in a thread pool """
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    future_func1 = executor.submit(synchronous_func1)
    func1_result = future_func1.result()
    future_func2 = executor.submit(synchronous_func2)
    func2_result = future_func2.result()
    response_txt = "OK"
    return Response(response_txt, media_type="text/plain")

routes = [
    Route("/simple", endpoint=simple_slow),
    Route("/slow_dj_funcs", endpoint=call_slow_dj_funcs),
]

app = Starlette(debug=True, routes=routes)
```

you could for example run this code with

```
pip install uvicorn
uvicorn --port 8002 miniasyncio:app
```

then on your web server route these specific urls to uvicorn and not to your django application server.

Comment: how can i receive an HTTP request directly to channel i have to use web sockets for that i guess and I want to give it as an API. So, how can channels help in this scenario?

Comment: That was exactly my question as I don't know your scenario or use case. If it had been for a browser app you could have used websockets for the asynchronous part. If you want to have a pure M2M api, then of course not.

I just made the experience that it might sometimes be interesting to see slightly different suggestions.

Comment: Enhanced my answer. If you can go with Django 3 and you're willing to play with bleeding edge features, this is the way to go.

I personally use slightly older technology for production and very new technology for toy projects, personal projects and proof of concept projects.

If I get conclusive results I think about using in production.

Comment: It's not just for browsers, API can be used in any android, ios apps or any thing that is capable of sending an http request. So websockets won't work. I was thinking os something like asyncio or any other asynch libraries await functionality (Master-Slave concept) but not sure if its the best way. Also celery gives an timeout functionality any idea if it works similar to await of asyncio?

Comment: I don't know about nginx much so can you tell if asyncio await or nginx will be a better solution?

Comment: enhanced my answer.

The question is very broad, so answers will be very broad.

Perhaps you can post another more specific question lateron. If you want to you can comment to my answer, so that I don't miss the new question.

Comment: @gelonida see this `https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html` won't this work?

Comment: See my last comment on your question. A lot depends on the details that you give.

In general celery is not intended for what you want to do.
One typical celery use case is for example. :
you have an http request treated by django, some actions that will need quite some time will be delegated to celery (sending many mails, creating an archive) **but** django will **return immediately** with a status code after the the task as been delegated to celery. You on the other hand want to wait, which means the process/thread  blocks and can't handle any other django request.

Comment: Another celery use case is to run periodic tasks. (e.g. a cleanup  your database or create a report every day at a certain time). 
This does not give what you seem to want:
A blocking http request which does not block the django worker. At least this is my interpretation of your question.

Back to your use case. You seem to want a low resource way of having many requests being blocked without blocking the django / http workers.

Celery doesn't handle http requests you need something like a browser plugin or an ASGI server and django 3.x or something like my tiny starlette example

Comment: okay understood, thanks man. I thought celery asyncresult and get works similar to asyncio's await as celery's get provides timeout functionality so I thought it might work.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use the futur `async` API, which will be proposed on Django in 3.1 release (which is already available in alpha)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.1/#asynchronous-views-and-middleware-support

(however, you will need to use an ASGI Web Worker to make it work properly)

Comment: I'll have to use the await functionality to achieve this, won't that block the API anyway? Also timeout in celery might do the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: As long as your in an async loop, you can add an async task without awaiting using `create_task` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task)

Comment: Of course, you could use celery, but then, you'll need to add a Celery worker, a broker server, eventually a Celery Heartbeat, and add all the Celery stack to your project.

Comment: of you go with asyncio you could use celery, but probably just using a threadpool for the slow tasks and using your blocking code there should be fine.

Comment: @gelonida can you share an example as answer

Comment: @Blusky see this `https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html` won't this work?

Answer (score -2):

Checkout Django 3 ASGI (Asynchronous Server Gateway Interface) support:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/asgi/

Comment: Isn't this identical to @Bluesky's answer?